# Python in SQL Server: NULL values in INT columns get mapped to -2147483648 rather than None

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

## tl;dr

I am working with Python in SQL Server 2017. The Python code is wrapped in a stored procedure to which I pass a query. The query gets evaluated and the data passed to Python. If a string column (char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar) within the query contains `NULL`, it gets mapped in Python to `None`. But if a `int` column contains `NULL`, it gets mapped to `-2147483648` (I guess minimum integer value).

My question is how to get a `NULL` value from a `int` column to be `None` in Python, rather than `-2147483648`? The column needs to stay `int`.

## Reproducable example

Test data I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table](
    [a-string] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [a-date] [date] NULL,
    [a-int] [int] NULL,
    [a-null-int] [int] NULL,
    [a-null-str] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test_table] ([a-string], [a-date], [a-int], [a-null-int], [a-null-str]) VALUES (N'asdf', CAST(N'2018-04-11' AS Date), 1, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[test_table] ([a-string], [a-date], [a-int], [a-null-int], [a-null-str]) VALUES (N'fdsa', CAST(N'2008-04-11' AS Date), 2, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[test_table] ([a-string], [a-date], [a-int], [a-null-int], [a-null-str]) VALUES (N'Bob "Bla" Bob', CAST(N'2028-04-11' AS Date), 3, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[test_table] ([a-string], [a-date], [a-int], [a-null-int], [a-null-str]) VALUES (N'Bob, Bob', CAST(N'2038-04-11' AS Date), 4, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[test_table] ([a-string], [a-date], [a-int], [a-null-int], [a-null-str]) VALUES (N'Bob bob', CAST(N'1998-04-11' AS Date), 5, 1, NULL)
```

The two last columns contain some `NULL` values. The first one is of type `int`, the second type `nvarchar`.

The code of the stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_test]
    @query NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
EXEC sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python', 
@script = N'
print(InputDataSet)
',
@input_data_1 = @query
END;
```

The stored procedure has one parameter with a query which passes the result of the query to the Python code. In the Python code I am printing the data.

How I execute the stored procedure:

```
EXEC [dbo].[usp_test] N'SELECT [a-string],CAST([a-date] as nvarchar(20)) as [a-date],[a-int],[a-null-int],[a-null-str] FROM [dbo].[test_table]'
```

The Result is:

```
        a-string      a-date  a-int  a-null-int a-null-str
0           asdf  2018-04-11      1 -2147483648       None
1           fdsa  2008-04-11      2 -2147483648       None
2  Bob "Bla" Bob  2028-04-11      3 -2147483648       None
3       Bob, Bob  2038-04-11      4 -2147483648       None
4        Bob bob  1998-04-11      5           1       None
```

The unexpected behaviour is in the column `a-null-int`. How do I get it to be `None` rather than `-2147483648`, while staying `int`?

This question strongly relates to SQL Server. According [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/python/new-components-in-sql-server-to-support-python-integration?view=sql-server-2017) by Microsoft, the BxlServer or SQL Satellite (not sure) handles data transfer between SQL Server and Python. I expect the problem to be in one of those services. But I have no idea on how to circumvent it.

#### Research done:

- Microsoft Tutorial for Python in SQL Server: [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/wrap-python-in-tsql-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017)
- SQL Server 2017 architecture for running Python: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/python/new-components-in-sql-server-to-support-python-integration?view=sql-server-2017
- Pandas support for integer `NA`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na

#### Edit1; Is this question a duplicate to the question [How to store empty value as an Integerfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399717)?

IMO not. It seems the problem there has been a discrepancy between data types (str vs int). This is not the case here. If I check the data type, I get:

```
print(type(InputDataSet.ix[0,"a-null-int"]))
>>> <class 'numpy.int32'>
```

This is correct. I am passing a `int` column in, and it gets mapped to a python `int`. But what I need is it to be `None`.

#### Edit2; Response to @arun-gurunathan answer:

Before I begin I need to state, that the `[a-null-int]` column needs to stay integer typed. For context, I need to export data to a CSV. To illustrate my problem, I changed the value of the last row in the `[a-null-int]` column from `NULL` to `1`. Changed the beginning of the question accordingly.

With `RxMissingValues.int32()` I get the value used for substituting `NULL` values, which is `-2147483648`. I can replace these values with `numpy.NaN`. It is not a bullet proof fix, because what happens if a column in SQL Server contains exactly this value? Nevertheless, I continued down this path...

The following code I put in the stored procedure above:

```
import numpy
from revoscalepy import RxMissingValues
InputDataSet.loc[InputDataSet["a-null-int"] == RxMissingValues.int32(), ("a-null-int")] = numpy.NaN
print(InputDataSet)
```

This is what I've got (abbreviated):

```
   a-null-int
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         1.0
```

The `[a-null-int]` column gets transformed to `float`. This behavior is documented in [pandas doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na) and has been discussed on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value).

I expect that my problem is not solvable due to NumPy limitations in handling of `NA` values. I'll wait some more to see if some more answers pop up on how I can keep the type of column `a-null-int` as `int`, or some workaround. Else I will accept @arun-gurunathan answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store empty value as an Integerfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399717/how-to-store-empty-value-as-an-integerfield)

Comment: @JacobH I don't think so. Added an explanation to the end of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rxMissingValues document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/python-reference/revoscalepy/rxmissingvalues) describes the pandas/numpy limitation of storing None values in integer columns. You can handle these by checking for missing value(rxMissingValues.int32()) as described in the document.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it helped me with further investigation. Added "Edit2" to the question.